# I need to disable touchpad

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

how to disable touchpad automatically when I either log in or the machine wakes up? To disable it I run

```
xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0
```

but every time the system is suspended and woken up, touchpad gets enabled again. I do not know why. Where do I need to put this command? which file? so that it is run on resume/reboot? I just need my touch pad disabled forever.

Answer (score 1):

Type this into your terminal(CTRL+ALT+T):

```
sudo gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled false
```

To disable your touchpad permanently.

Comment: thanks. I am not using gnome, I am on Unity DE.